# Short story about people trapped in a cave, while time shifts around them

Tags: story-identification

This a short story about an unnamed pioneer/settler woman in charge of a group of people living in a cave. Time keeps shifting outside the cave, and they end up in different eras/epochs in history. She is also making some sort of tapestry(?) which she realises is a map or guide to where they'll end up next.

We thought this might have been a Stephen King story but couldn't find it. It was read in the last few years as part of an anthology (in paperback, pre e-readers), but unfortunately we've no idea when it might have been published.

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly Dame Anne McCaffrey's ["A Flock of Geese"](http://www.librarything.com/work/9556745)?

> The cave was populated by random refugees, not an organized party. One woman ran the group; she would have preferred a permanent group who didn't challenge her authority, but so far it hadn't happened. Her greatest advantage was that she could sense when a time-shift was about to occur and could get back to safety. The cave was a safe place because it was in a place that hadn't changed geologically during human history.

It [shows up in](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?66936) *Moonsinger's Friends* and *The Girl Who Heard Dragons*.

And it's a quilt that she's working on according to the [Google Books excerpt](http://books.google.com/books?id=Xlp2k39LXfIC&pg=PA167&lpg=PA167&dq=%22a+flock+of+geese%22+mccaffery&source=bl&ots=oS-rTw7AiK&sig=792-dOA_x3JKXh_qkzWrrXlFerU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=pkq7U5axE6G-sQTb3IGYBQ&ved=0CB4Q6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q=%22a%20flock%20of%20geese%22%20mccaffery&f=false) that I've found.

There is a second linked story, included in *The Girl Who Heard Dragons*, "The Bones Do Lie".